# Buttons missing when moving from 1 worksheet to another

Tags: excel, vba

```
Dim ws As Worksheets
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

On Error Resume Next
    Set ws = Sheets("Details")

Range("DetailsOutput").ClearContents
Sheets("WorkSh1").Visible = True
Sheets("WorkSh1").Select
Sheets("Details").Visible = False
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"))
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

After this code control goes to "WorkSh1", the buttons in a row becomes invisible but still can be selected. If i debug, buttons seems to be appearing normally. Issue appear while running normally
Along with it, a button from "Details" worksheet too appears in "WorkSh1" but can't select it. What can try?

Comment: What is the point of above code? What type of button? Why is it waiting 5 seconds? If you remove the `on error` statement, does it have any errors?

Comment: Code was for a button event - so that when clicked takes us a old worksheet. used a for button. Used wait sec to see if refresh happens which it didn't. 
The code became working for me when switched "Application.ScreenUpdating = True" at start and false at end.